# Ant and Junit test java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, linux, ant, junit

I'm having a problem with an ant build.xml file that's giving me a java.lang.ClassNotFoundExcpetion.  I am able to run it fine on windows, but when I port it over to a Linux vm, I get the exception.

```
<project name="OBJECT" default="compile" >
<!--
Properties for the directories of .java
These are the locations the the source files
These are the locations of the .jar dependancy
 -->
<property name="src.dir" location="src"/>
<property name="src.java.dir" location="${src.dir}/csc439"/>
<property name="src.test.dir" location="${src.dir}/test"/>
<property name="lib.dir" location="lib"/>

<!--
Properties for the directories of .class
This gets deleted when ant clean is run
 -->
<property name="target.dir" location="target"/>
<property name="target.classes.java.dir" location="${target.dir}/classes/java"/>
<property name="target.classes.test.dir" location="${target.dir}/classes/test"/>

<!--Properties for the report directory-->
<property name="target.report.dir" location="${target.dir}/report"/>
<!-- 
compile.java 
Creates a directory for the .class files of the Java files for the file being tested
Compiles the files and places the .class into the java file created
Imports the necissary .jar files from the lib directory
-->
<target name="compile.java">
        <mkdir dir="${target.classes.java.dir}"/>
        <javac includeantruntime="true" destdir="${target.classes.java.dir}">
            <src path="${src.java.dir}"/> 
            <classpath> 
                <pathelement location="${target.classes.java.dir}"/>
                    <pathelement location="${lib.dir}"/>
                <fileset dir="${lib.dir}"> 
                    <include name="*.jar"/>
                </fileset> 
            </classpath> 
        </javac>
    </target>
<!-- 
compile.test 
Depends on compile.java to complete first
Creates a directory for the .class files of the Test files
Compiles the files and places the .class into the test file created
-->
<target name="compile.test" depends="compile.java">
    <mkdir dir="${target.classes.test.dir}"/>
    <javac includeantruntime="true" destdir="${target.classes.test.dir}">
        <src path="${src.test.dir}"/>
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${target.classes.java.dir}"/>
                <pathelement location="${lib.dir}"/>
            <fileset dir="${lib.dir}"> 
                <include name="*.jar"/>
            </fileset> 
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>
<!-- 
compile
This the the default
Depends on compile.java, and compile.test
-->
<target name="compile" depends="compile.java,compile.test"/>
<!-- 
test
Depends on compile
Creates the report file
Runs the JUnit test TestCacheSuite in the test file in the test .class directory
--> 
<target name="test" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${target.report.dir}"/>
    <junit printsummary="yes" haltonerror="yes" haltonfailure="yes" fork="yes">
        <formatter type="plain" usefile="false"/>
            <formatter type="xml"/>
        <test name="test.TestMediaPlayer" todir="${target.report.dir}"/>
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${target.classes.java.dir}"/>
            <pathelement location="${target.classes.test.dir}"/>
        </classpath>
    </junit>
</target>   
<!-- 
report
Depends on test
Creates the file for html documents
Depends on Test
Creates a Junit report 
--> 
<target name="report" depends="test">
    <mkdir dir="${target.report.dir}/html"/>
    <junitreport todir="${target.report.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${target.report.dir}">
            <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
        </fileset>
        <report todir="${target.report.dir}/html"/>
    </junitreport>
</target>
<!--
clean
Deletes the target directory
This file contains all of the .class files
This file contains all of the reports
-->
<target name = "clean">
    <delete dir = "${target.dir}"/>
</target>
```

This is the error I get while running it on linux.

```
    [junit] Running test.MockObject
[junit] Testsuite: test.MockObject
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
[junit]
[junit]     Caused an ERROR
[junit] test.MockObject
[junit] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.MockObject
[junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
[junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
[junit]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
[junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
[junit]
```

With the exact same build file I get it to run fine on windows.

I have run it fine from command line on windows, as well as using Eclipse both work flawlessly.

From everything that I read it says that I need to check the CLASSPATH, and PATH variables. 
I have done this, but I must be doing something wrong.  I don't understand why with the same build information that it would run in one os, and not the other.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please check your properties of directories, slashes are different in both OSes. Also, check if the compiled classes really are in the directories ant expects. Other things might be file permissions, but I guess would result in 'compile' target fails during mkdir.

Comment: the directories should be where they are.  Like I said, it runs fine in windows, just not linux.  the slashes should be fine because they are relative directories and the building would not work as you said.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't tons and tons of information to go on, but to hazard a guess, I'd say you needed to add your `${lib.dir}` as a `<pathelement>` in the classpath of your junit invocation.

Comment: The problem is the testing in the ant build file.  lib is only needed to compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
<echoproperties/>
```

This is your best friend in such cases. If it runs fine on windows, but does not run on linux, then it must be some problem with the file separator (however with ant / works on windows as well), or simply you have different current directory (you use relative path everywhere). If you have different current directory, you will see it in the output of `echoproperties` as `"user.dir"`. You can set also the `javac` to `verbose="true"` and then you can compare the windows output of the script with the linux output.

Answer (score 0):

For me this issue arose because my test file used an inner class. this is compiled as a seperate classfile in eclipse and you will need both classname.class and classname$1.class for ant to run your test.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding junit jar location to your classpath element. I don't know how but that worked for me!

Something like,

```
       <classpath>
            <pathelement location="path/to/junit/jar"/>
            <pathelement location="${target.classes.java.dir}"/>
            <pathelement location="${target.classes.test.dir}"/>
        </classpath>
```